# Why doesn't my Farfetch'd evolve after landing 3 critical hits in a battle?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

In Pokemon FireRed/LeafGreen, my Farfetch'd has landed 3 critical-hit in a single battle and leveled up right after that but it still doesn't evolve. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because Fire Red/Leaf Green is Generation 3, and only has the Kantonian form of Farfetch'd. In order to evolve Farfetch'd into Sirfetch'd, you need the Galarian form, which can only be acquired Generation 8 onward.